# how to prevent Ubuntu 14 to upgrade to version 16

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I have to install and maintain "snpservices" that requires "php5".
So, I installed an Ubuntu 14.04 that comes with php5 and it worked fine.

But Ubuntu likes to update, so it went into 16.04, where php7 comes,
so my snpservices crashed.

My quetion is : how do I do to prevent Ubuntu to go from 14.04 into 16.04 ?

The easy answer is "never run 'apt-get upgrade'" 
but I would like something more expeditive, maybe CloneZilla ...

Any ideas ?
Thanks.

Comment: google uninstall php ubuntu then
sudo apt-get install php5-fpm php5-mysql to  install php5

Comment: that command will prevent my Ubuntu to go from 14.04 to 16.02 on sudo apt-get upgrade ?

Comment: No, they're suggesting you just uninstall the default PHP (7 in the case of Ubuntu 16.4) and install PHP5 specifically.

Comment: Ubuntu won't upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 on its own.  That's something you need to explicitly do outside of the package manager's automatic updates.  It will stay at 14.04 forever until it is no longer supported.  However, if the 14.04 repository receives a php upgrade, the software updater will offer it.  You can choose to hide updates for the package, and it won't offer it again.  LTS releases are supported for 5 yrs, so anything older than that won't be maintained and won't offer updates.  V14.04 just passed 5 yrs.  Verify that the php source points to the 14.04 repository.